# MPMediaPicker not showing all songs

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmediapickercontroller, apple-music

#### Usage

I am using a media picker like this

```
musicPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];
musicPicker.showsCloudItems               = false;
musicPicker.showsItemsWithProtectedAssets = true;
musicPicker.delegate                      = self;
musicPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems    = false;
musicPicker.prompt                        = NSLocalizedString(@"Select a song", @"Select a song");
[self presentViewController:musicPicker animated:true completion:nil];
```

#### Issue

The issue is that I do **not** see all the *downloaded* files that I see in the regular Apple Music app. Is there anything to consider? Why are not all songs showing up?